# WcfSvcHost.exe access violation exception on every WCF project VS2013

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, visual-studio-2013

I have such problem in **VS2013**:

Whenever I try to debug a WCF Library project I get an error on startup:

> An unhandled exception of type '**System.AccessViolationException**' occurred in **WcfSvcHost.exe**.

It's the same even when trying debugging a fresh WCF project from template - does not work.
Event viewer:

> *.NET Runtime exception*
>   App: WcfSvcHost.exe
>   Ver: v4.0.30319
> Exception: System.AccessViolationException

Stack:

```
in System.Net.UnsafeNclNativeMethods.SetFileCompletionNotificationModes(CriticalHandle handle, FileCompletionNotificationModes modes)
in System.Net.HttpListener.CreateRequestQueueHandle()
in System.Net.HttpListener.Start()
in System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.OnOpen()
in System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManager.Open(TransportChannelListener channelListener)
in System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManagerContainer.Open(SelectTransportManagersCallback selectTransportManagerCallback)
in System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
in System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
in System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelDispatcher.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
in System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
in System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
in System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
in Microsoft.Tools.SvcHost.ServiceHostHelper.OpenService(ServiceInfo info)
in Microsoft.Tools.SvcHost.ServiceHostHelper.OpenService(System.String)
in Microsoft.Tools.SvcHost.MainForm.theBackgroundWorker_DoWork(System.Object, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)
in System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(System.Object)
in System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr, System.Object[], System.Object, System.Object[] ByRef)
in System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessageSink)
in System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
in System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
in System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
in System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()`
```

Application error in event viewer:

> App causing error: WcfSvcHost.exe, ver: 12.0.21005.1, timestamp: 0x524fc58b
>   Module causing error: KERNELBASE.dll, ver: 6.3.9600.17278, timestamp: 0x53eebf2e
>   Exception code: 0xe0434352
>   Causing process ID: 0x8d8
>   Error application path: **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\WcfSvcHost.exe**
>   Error module path: **C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll**
>   **Windows: 8.1 Pro x64**, all available updates in
>   **VS 2013 Pro version 12.0.31101.00 Update 4**

I will be very grateful for any help, banging my head against the wall with this..

Comment: Try running it as Administrator. If that works, you want to look at this command `netsh http add acl`.

Comment: Tried that before - didn't help unfortunately

Comment: Try `netstat -an` and give me the output. Do you run Skype?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/qPGEX6YK I do.

Comment: Sorry...stumped, port 80 isn't being used...>_<

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue with `HttpListener` while using `WebApi\SignalR Owin` on Windows 8.

In my code I was Calling: 
`WebApp.Start<Startup>(url);`
Throws an access violation in `System.Net.UnsafeNclNativeMethods.SetFileCompletionNotificationModes`.

Turns out that "some" third party programs are not compatible with Microsoft's ifs winsock lsps. For me it was Lavasoft's "Web Companion". (Which uninstalled fixed the issue)

See
[Handshake exception occurring when connecting to SQL Server Azure with .NET 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12082077/handshake-exception-occurring-when-connecting-to-sql-server-azure-with-net-4-5)

[SetFileCompletionNotificationModes seems to not work properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22617539/setfilecompletionnotificationmodes-seems-to-not-work-properly)

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2568167

Hope this helps.