# KES build index System.AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services

We are building a interactive search for our users and I tried this Microsoft KES  [link](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/kes/documentation/gettingstarted) which lookg good.

When I try to host service

```
kes.exe host_service d:\kes\grammarout.grammar d:\kes\indexout.index
```

I ran into following issue,

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at System.Net.UnsafeNclNativeMethods.SetFileCompletionNotificationModes(CriticalHandle handle, FileCompletionNotificationModes modes)
   at System.Net.HttpListener.CreateRequestQueueHandle()
   at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()
   at Kes.WebServer.Start()
   at Kes.KesWebServiceCmd.ExecuteInt()
   at Kes.KesWebServiceCmd.Execute()
   at Kes.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

I tried running command prompt as administrator but same issue is popping up.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try explicitly setting the port to a different value?

```
kes.exe host_service Academic.grammar Academic.index --port 9999
```

If this does not work, a search for this particular error message coming from SetFileCompletionNotificationModes() [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27249333/wcfsvchost-exe-access-violation-exception-on-every-wcf-project-vs2013) that this may be due to interference from a 3rd party app.  Do you have any application installed that may intercept network traffic?